# Screen suddenly goes black when I adjust the screen but returns when I close and reopen the lid

Tags: ubuntu, laptop

This issue just happened suddenly tonight.

I was using my laptop. The laptop is running Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME 3.26. When I slightly adjust the screen or press the sides near the display of my laptop, it suddenly turns off then on and off again until it doesn't turn on again. But, the machine itself is still on. The audio can still be heard.

However, when I close the lid and reopen it again, most of the time, the screen would be turned on again and I am greeted by the lock screen.

On some occasions, when I rebooted my laptop, the screen will stay on then turn off again after the "BIOS" (not sure with the proper term) screen.

What could be the cause of this problem and how do I solve it? I am leaning towards the thinking that this is a hardware issue.

UPDATE 1: The screen turned off when I was moving the laptop. I adjusted the screen, and closed and reopened it again but to no avail. I rebooted the laptop after this. To my surprise, the screen turned on!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hardware issue.

The cable from the screen to the base goes through the hinge. With repeated opening and closing, the cable insulation wears through or the core of one of the wires breaks, causing a problem.

I have an old Samsung NC10 and have replaced this cable twice over the years. It wasn't too difficult (thanks to Google and YouTube): just a screwdriver to open the case then unplug the old cable and plug in the new one.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps. However, I noticed that the display goes out more often whenever I plug my laptop in. When it is not, it only goes off when the table it sits on is bumped.